# Can anyone name this plant please?

Tags: identification

Green leaved. No Flowers. Grows from about April to October. Prefers shade or partial shade.

[image: 1]

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Comment: Does it disappear completely below ground in winter, or retain woody branches above ground?

Comment: I realize this is months' later, but what height does it get? What kind of soil is it growing in? It looks like you're using pebbles as a mulch - is their fabric under it?